# Bitwise multiplication to achieve result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, multiplication, bit-shift, bit

Is there a general set of rules to achieve a certain number by multiplying a known and unknown number.
e.g.
Suppose x = 13 and z = 9

Is there a way to find y such that

```
    x * y = z     
=> 13 * y = 9
```

I don't want to utilize them as mathematical integers, but rather in terms of bits. So, I want to keep z an int.
Obviously, there is an overflow in the bit representation, but I'm unsure how to find z without brute forcing all values in a 32-bit machine. I think y would be a very small number, negative.

Note: this isn't or a hw assignment, so you could change x and y to whatever, these are just examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, find the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `x` (13) mod 2<sup>32</sup>. There are several ways to do it, many people will recommend the extended Euclidean algorithm, but it is not the simplest for this case. See Hacker's Delight chapter 10 (integer division by constants) for a simpler algorithm.

Anyway, once you know that the modular multiplicative inverse of 13 mod 2<sup>32</sup> is `0xc4ec4ec5`, multiply that number by `z` to get `y`.

`0xc4ec4ec5 * 9 = 0xec4ec4ed`

So `y = 0xec4ec4ed`, and `0xec4ec4ed * 13` is indeed 9.

Note that if `x` is even, it has no inverse. If it's "at most as even as `z`" (that is, it has as many or fewer trailing zeroes than `z`) you can solve it this way after dividing out their highest common power of 2.

Comment: this is used for fast division on compiler optimizations