# How to perform division of 2 numbers by inverse multiplication using Bitwise

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, division, inverse

Here is the code I divide 2 numbers by bit shifting . But I heard there is a faster way, which is to convert division to inverse multiplication.

```
int divv(int num1, int  num2 )
{
        bool acc = false;
        if(num1<0 && num2>0)
        {
                num1 = -num1;
                acc = true;
        }
        else if( num1 > 0 && num2 <0)
        {
                num2 = -num2;
                acc = true;
        }
        else if ( num1 < 0 && num2 <0 )
        {
                num1 = -num1;
                num2 = -num2;
        }
        int ans = 0;
        while(num1 >= num2)
 {
long temp = num2, count = 1;
        if(temp <= num1)
        {
                        temp <<= 1;
                        count <<= 1;
        }
        ans += count >> 1;
        num1 -= temp >> 1;
}

        return acc?(-ans):(ans);

}
```

can anyone help me understand the implementation of division by inverse multiplication? Note that only bitwise operators can be used

Comment: Is your question similar to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988170/bitwise-multiplication-to-achieve-result

Comment: I didn't find much useful information from your link either. Anyway thank you for that.